# Emulate ff-only behaviour on Git 1.6.0.2

Tags: linux, git, fast-forward

I have the following problem on one of our servers: I want a user that pulls from a Git repo on a regular basis (using a cronjob), but only doing fast-forward pulls (the content on the server changes sometimes, too). With modern Git (1.6.6 and newer), I can simply do

```
git pull --ff-only origin master
```

but since I only have 1.6.0.2 installed, I can't do that. I thought I could work around it by doing

```
git config merge.ff only
git pull origin master
```

but as it turned out, that did not work (no error, it still does merges though). Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this by manually checking if the current branch (`master`) is actually a descendant of the branch to be merged (`origin/master`):

```
git fetch origin
if [ $(git branch --contains master -a | grep origin/master) ]
then
    git merge origin/master
else
    echo "No fast-forward, aborting merge"
fi
```